# Put 3 coordinate data point to 2D plane in python

Tags: python

I am trying to create scatter plot plane using python.

This plane has 3 coordinate data point `p1=(x1, y1, z1)`

My x,y,z values are coming from external.

now i want to display this `p1` point in 2D plane like below image. This 3 axis are  perpendicular  to each other.
I am very glad if someone can give me an answer!

[image: Here is attachement]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: give you code which you trying.

Comment: i try to use matplotlib 3D chart but that is not i want.

Comment: aviboy2006 i'm new to python, so i have no idea how can do this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s about coordinate geometry, not programming.